# What does character encoding in C programming language depend on?

Tags: c, gcc, character-encoding

What does character encoding in C programming language depend on? (OS? compiler? or editor?)
I'm working on not only characters of ASCII but also ones of other encodings such as UTF-8.

How can we check the current character encodings in C?

Comment: All relevant C program text (except contents of string constants) can be encoded in ASCII. (All keywords and other characters are part of it.) The program you write in C may handle any encoding you are able to deal with. Some are supported by standard libraries, some by system functions. It thus depends on the libraries which are available. (IMHO, a character of any encoding can be expressed using one of the integral types of C.) This doesn't mean you can use every Unicode character literally in a C character or string constant. But you always can encode it using octal or hex sequences.

Comment: e.g. `"\303\274"` is an "ü" encoded in UTF-8. (The source code itself is ASCII-only.)

Comment: @Scheff : That looks a lot like an answer rather then a comment.

Comment: @Clifford yeah, but it cannot be down-voted. ;-) Though, I dare to make it an answer...

Comment: @Scheff : Be brave!

Comment: [`locale`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html)

Comment: Character encoding for `a,b,c,A,B,C,0,1,2, #,^,&,*` etc. (characters of the source code)  must be positives values.  `01,2,3,...9` must be sequential.  Not much else _required_.

Answer (score 2):

The C source code might be stored in distinct encodings. This is clearly *compiler* dependent (i.e. a compiler setting if available). Though, I wouldn't count on it and count on ASCII-only always. (IMHO this is the most portable way to write code.)

Actually, you can encode any character of any encoding using only ASCIIs in C source code if you encode them with octal or hex sequences. (This is what I do from time to time to earn respect of my colleagues – writing German texts with `\303\244`, `\303\266`, `\303\274`, `\303\231` into translation tables out of mind...)

Example: `"\303\274"` encodes the UTF-8 sequence for a string constant "ü". (But if I print this on my Windows console I only get "��" although I set code page 65001 which should provide UTF-8. The damn Windows console...)

The program written in C may handle any encoding you are able to deal with. Actually, the characters are only numbers which can be stored as one of the available integral types (e.g. `char` for ASCII and UTF-8, other `int` types for encodings with 16 or 32 bit wide characters). As already mentioned by [Clifford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168986/clifford), the output decides what to do with these numbers. Thus, this is *platform* dependent.

To handle characters according to a certain encoding, (e.g. make it upper case or lower case, local dictionary-like sorting, etc.) you have to use an appropriate library. This might be part of the standard libaries, the system libraries, or 3rd party libraries.

This is especially true for conversion from one encoding to another. This is a good point to mention [libintl](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libintl.htm).

I personally prefer ASCII, Unicode, and UTF-8 (and unfortunately UTF-16 as I'm doing most work on Windows 10). In this special case, the conversion can be done by a pure "bit-fiddling" algorithm (without any knowledge of special characters). You may have a look at Wikipedia [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) to get a clue. By google, you probably will find something ready-to-use if you don't want to do it by yourself.

<s>The standard library of C++11 and C++14 provides support also (e.g. [`std::codecvt_utf8`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8)) but it is remarked as deprecated in C++17. Thus, I don't need to throw away my bit-fiddling code (I'm so proud of).</s> Oops. This is tagged with [c](/questions/tagged/c) – sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is *platform* or display device/framework dependent.  The compiler does not care how the platform interprets either `char` or `wchar_t` when such values are rendered as glyphs on some display device.

If the output were to some remote terminal, then the rendering would be dependent on the terminal rather than the execution environment, while in a desktop computer, the rendering may be to a text console or to a GUI, and the resulting rendering may differ even between those.